# IndexOutOfBoundsException when clicking RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android

Having problem when clicking items of RecyclerView, app crashes and giving the output:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 20
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.google.gson.JsonArray.get(JsonArray.java:147)
        at com.devpocket.kvartirka.MainActivity.itemClicked(MainActivity.java:334)
        at com.devpocket.kvartirka.Adapters.OffersAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(OffersAdapter.java:161)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5162)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20873)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 20
```

The code which I'm using is like this, this is an adapter:

```
public class OffersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ClickListener clickListener;

private CityData cityData;

private ArrayList<CityData> cityItemList = new ArrayList<CityData>();
private Context mContext;
private String text;

public static Button headerButton1;

public OffersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CityData> cityItemList, String text) {
    this.cityItemList = cityItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int viewType;

    if (position == 0) {
        viewType = 0;
    } else {
        viewType = 1;
    }

    return viewType;
}

@Override
public OffersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (viewType == 0) {
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.logo_layout, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView, viewType);
    } else {
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.offers_singleitem, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView, viewType);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OffersAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if (position > 0) {
        cityData = cityItemList.get(position-1);
        String type = cityData.getType();

        if ("flat".equals(type)) {
            viewHolder.address.setText(cityData.getAddress());
            viewHolder.description.setText(cityData.getDescription());
            viewHolder.roomNumbers.setText(cityData.getRoomNumbers());
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cityData.getMetro())) {
                viewHolder.metroImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            viewHolder.metro.setText(cityData.getMetro());
            viewHolder.prices.setText(cityData.getPrices() + " ₽");
            Ion.with(viewHolder.offerImage)
                    .fitXY()
                    .load(cityData.getURL());
        } else if("cottage".equals(type)) {
            viewHolder.address.setText(cityData.getAddress());
            viewHolder.description.setText(cityData.getDescription());
            viewHolder.roomNumbers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.cottageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cityData.getMetro())) {
                viewHolder.metroImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            viewHolder.metro.setText(cityData.getMetro());
            viewHolder.prices.setText(cityData.getPrices() + " ₽");
            Ion.with(viewHolder.offerImage)
                    .fitXY()
                    .load(cityData.getURL());
        }
    }

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView roomNumbers; //количество комнат
    public TextView address; //адресс квартиры
    public TextView description; //описание квартиры
    public TextView metro; //описание квартиры
    public TextView prices; //цена за день
    public ImageView offerImage; //картинка квартиры
    public ImageView cottageImage; //обозначение коттеджа
    public ImageView metroImageView; //значок метро

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int position) {
        super(itemView);


        if(position > 0) {
            roomNumbers = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomNumbers);
            address = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.conditionsTextView);
            metro = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.metroTextView);
            offerImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            prices = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
            cottageImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cottageImage);
            metroImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.metroImageView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            headerButton1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerButton1);
            headerButton1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
            headerButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FilterActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(clickListener != null) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clickListener.itemClicked(v, getPosition());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != cityItemList ? cityItemList.size() : 0);
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ClickListener {
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
}

}
```

And this is how adding data into adapter:

```
private ArrayList<CityData> cityList = new ArrayList<CityData>();

CityData cityItem = new CityData();
cityItem.setAddress(String.valueOf(flatAddress));
cityItem.setType(type);
cityItem.setDescription(description);
cityItem.setRoomNumbers(rooms);
cityItem.setMetro(metro);
cityItem.setUrl(imageURL);
cityItem.setPrices(day);
cityList.add(cityItem);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);
```

And the on itemClicked

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

    String offerData = null;

    for(int i = 0; i <= position; i++ ) {

        if(i == position) {
            JsonElement obj = jsonObjectToPass.get(position-1);
            offerData = String.valueOf(obj);
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfferInfo.class);
    intent.putExtra("offerData", offerData);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: It crashed in your itemClicked function, you need to show us that.

Comment: You are trying to access data which is not present the size of the list is 20 but are accessing the 24th element which is causing the application to crash.

Comment: First off-  your code is weird.  Why do you have a for loop if you only want to act on a single index of it?  The loop does nothing.  It makes me think you copy pasted some code without understanding it.

Secondly, your code seems to assume that you have a json array who's length is at least equal to the size of your adapter.  Apparently that isn't the case.  Why do you assume the json array is that long?

Comment: @GabeSechan ah, now i see the problem to, no i didn't copied this code, LOL. Just forgot to make changes with json array.

Answer (score 2):

Change itemClicked() to this

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
     String offerData = null;

     JsonElement obj = jsonObjectToPass.get(position-1);
     offerData = String.valueOf(obj);

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfferInfo.class);
     intent.putExtra("offerData", offerData);
     intent.putExtra("position", position);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

No need of for loop while you are getting the position directly

Comment: If the jsonObjectToPass size is lesser than the position - 1, your solution will cause also a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line: `JsonElement obj = jsonObjectToPass.get(position-1);`

Without further information, you try to retrieve the element #24 (position == 25) when there is only 20 items in the list.

Maybe add a validation in your if like this:

```
if(i == position && jsonObjectToPass.size() < position) {
```

And check your condition, it seems wrong. Your code will enter in the if only one time in the for loop. So why putting a loop there ?